# Passing a external variable in JSON.parse function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to get a value from json by using the `JSON.parse` function. My json response is given below:

```
{
  "rows": 10,
  "os": "0",
  "page": "1",
  "total": "122",
  "projects": {
    "P143841": {
      "id": "P143841",
      "locations": [{
        "geoLocId": "0002220957",
        "latitude": "3.866667",
        "longitude": "11.516667"
      }],
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to get the value 10 if I do `JSON.parse(obj.rows)` but if I assign the rows to a variable say `var value = rows` and then I pass it to the `JSON.parse(obj.value)` function I got `undefined`.

P.S. I won't be knowing the names of the response parameters, i.e. i won't know if it will be `rows` or `os` quoting from the above example. I will be retrieving them from a database. If I perform the code below:

```
  for (var i=0;i<length;i++) {
    var value = responseParam_array[i];
    console.log(obj.value);
  }
```

I get the output but any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the other answers you shouldn't need to parse individual properties, just parse the original JSON and then operate on the resulting object.

But as for this problem:

> *"if I assign the rows to a variable say* `var value = rows` *and then I pass it to the* `JSON.parse(obj.value)` *function I got* `undefined`"

If `value` is a variable holding the name of a property of `obj` then you need:

```
obj[value]
// NOT
obj.value
```

When you use "dot" notation the part on the right of the dot is taken as the literal name of the property, not as a variable. Using the square-bracket syntax the expression in the brackets is evaluated and its result is taken as the property name.

Comment: I did as u suggested.But if i have to parse say obj.projects.P143841.locations[0].latitude and if i pass it into obj[value] i get as  undefined. (ie) obj[projects]will be printed but obj[projects.P143841.locations[0].latitude] is throwing undefined.Any suggestion will be really helpful

Comment: Try `obj[projects].P143841.locations[0].latitude`. If you're chaining multiple properties like that each one needs to use either dot notation or brackets, don't put the whole chain of names inside the same set of brackets. `obj[projects]["P143841"]["locations"][0].latitude` (and other variations) will also work.

Answer (score 1):

you should be json-parsing your whole object and using the parsed object afterwards (you dont need to parse every property for itself)

```
var strObj = '{"rows": 10,"os": "0","page": "1","total": "122","projects":{"P143841":{"id":"P143841",}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(strObj);
var rows = obj.rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
var str = '{ "some": "JSON String like the one above with", "rows": 10 }';
var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
var whatYouWant = parsed.rows;
```